# Compilation in Overleaf not same as local TeXworks

Tags: overleaf, texworks

I started a file in Overleaf (online), then cut-and-pasted the source code into my local TeXworks. Overleaf successfully compiles all the details: title page, TOC page, math and chapters, which consists of 21 pages total, just as expected. However, while the TeXworks file compiles, it only produces the title page, then an empty Contents page, then a blank page, nothing else. I used pdfLaTeX to compile. Any suggestions?

Comment: overleaf is a standard texlive so that isn't the difference, but it may be texlive of a different date, add `\listfiles` to your preamble and compare the file lists (and versions) in the lists. Also it won't just give no output with no error, what error do you get in the log? similarly texworks is just the text editor, what matters is which tex system, of which date you have locally.

Comment: Please don't close questions asked by new users before they even have time to read the comments asking for improvements!